# How to run GridSearchCV for k-means using spark_sklearn

Tags: apache-spark, scikit-learn, pyspark

I am trying to use GridSearchCV from spark_sklearn to speed up the fitting process on a 3 node spark cluster. However when I'm calling `.fit()`, there came some `pickle.loads(obj)` error and I think the essential issue is the following

> ImportError: No module named sklearn.cluster.k_means_

**If I submit the task in local mode, then everything works fine**. It seems either the cluster mode doesn't use the correct version of gridsearchcv or the sklearn were imported from different paths in cluster mode for the two workers. Can anybody help me?

spark_sklearn: 2.3.1

The most relevant part of the code is as follows:

```
    import spark_sklearn
    from spark_sklearn import GridSearchCV
    ....some code for spark context, data reading and preparation....
    parameters = {"n_clusters":[d/2,d],"max_iter":[100,200]}
    km = KMeans(init='k-means++')
    grid = GridSearchCV(sc, km, cv=5, param_grid = parameters, scoring = 
    silhouette)

    grid.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: can you please provide your code?

Comment: @addmeaning Thanks for helping. I have posted some relevant part of the code. If needed I can post the entire file here.

Comment: code looks ok. Does every node have installed `sklearn`?

Comment: @addmeaning Yes. I used conda to install "scikit-learn" on all 3 nodes and the version is 0.19.1. This reminds me that on the master node, I also have used pip to install scikit-learn (0.19.2), but if I uninstall this package, then there will be an error "no module named sklearn". (so the master node uses the pip scikit-learn instead of conda one)

Comment: How are you initializing the cluster (slaves)? Independently? Have you set the pyspark python driver version and path on all machines?

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to @addmeaning and @Vivek Kumar, I have finally found out the problem. It seems the pyspark.python pointed to a different path unexpectedly, so the packages used by the python is different (which also has sklearn). The reason why it was working in local mode but not cluster mode is that in these two modes, the python interpreters are different. So I specified in /conf/spark-defaults.conf which interpreter the cluster mode should use

```
spark.pyspark.python=/path/to/my/interpreter
```

or you can add pyspark.python=/path/my/interpreter to /etc/profile, or change it in spark_env.sh and things get working.